# Combining Two Containers

Tags: docker, windows, mysql, ubuntu

I'm working on a Windows laptop and running Docker for Windows on it. I want to run an Ubuntu container with a specific version and a MySQL server on it. So the question is, do I have to download MySQL on the Ubuntu container or can I run 2 containers (Ubuntu and MySQL) and combine them? How do I combine these 2 containers?

Answer (score 2):

At first, I misread your question, thinking you wanted to run more than one service together, so I had recommended [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose) which makes it easy to run multiple services together, with networking, and can even specify the start up order.

But now I see you are just trying to run MySQL, and wondering do you need separate containers for the OS and MySQL: in short, no you don't need two containers. Instead, just get the MySQL image from DockerHub at https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql?tab=description

The reason you can just use that MySQL Docker image by itself is because it already is installed on a Debian image, which you can see in the Dockerfile at https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/Dockerfile where it shows:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim
```

So, to solve the problem, do:

1. `docker pull mysql`
2. `docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag` as mentioned in the instructions on the Docker Hub page. Additional documentation at https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/mysql

I do strongly recommend using Docker Compose (`docker-compose` command) to run containers, as it makes it easier to organise and run them.

Comment: Thanks Mike this is really helpful. Actually you answered 2 things for me . So when i want a Debian container with mysql apache freeradius etc in it( with network config and so on) i do it with docker compose right?

Comment: @user19215 docker-compose is not required, but just a helpful way to run containers. You could instead do the same using docker commands, but docker-compose is much easier to configure (the `docker-compose.yml` is YAML syntax).

Comment: @user19215 So if you want multiple services in one container not in different ones that are connected via a network then you will have to create your own Docker image. This is pretty simple to do if you just want basic non production ready images.

Comment: @user19215 Here's official documentation on running multiple services in a single container: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Comment: @user19215 That being said it's not recommended as Docker containers are meant to be application containers, that is there should be a single service running in a single container. It sounds like what you want are OS containers like LXC: https://linuxcontainers.org/